# Adding two functions in one input tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, tags

I am trying to add two two `functions` in one input tag. BUT failed many times.

**What i am trying to do ?**

There are two functions in different `input` tags in my HTML template.

One for `add tag` by `,` .

AND second for `autocomplete`.

I am trying to add autocomplete and tags input in the same textinput, So i can use `autocomplete` and `add tag` at same time.

home.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}user_tags/css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">

<script src="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>




#This function is for `autocomplete`.    

<form>
    <label for="product">Product</label>
    <input type="text" name="product" id="product">
</form>
    
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

#This function is for `add tag`

        <b>Add Tags </b>
        <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control" name="tags">
        <br>
```

**What have i tried ?**

I see an answer that if i add `semicolons` at the end of the both tag then it will work BUT it didn't work for me.

```
<form>
    <label for="product">Product</label>
    <input type="text" name="product" id="product"; data-role="tagsinput";>
</form>
```

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: you may need to clarify what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "add them together"? There is no 'add tags' function shown.

Comment: UPDATED THE QUESTION

Comment: You can't wrap javascript functions in HTML tags. Explain what you're trying to do on a high level. Ignore the idea of wrapping functions in a tags.

Comment: I don't want to wrap `javascript function in tag` i just want to mix two `ids` in one `input tag`. JUST ID NOT FULL FUNCTION

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused what you are asking. If you are trying to mark an element (input) to be selected by different queries, you can use classes. If you are trying to run 2 functions with one function call, wrap the two functions in a single function.

Comment: How can i wrap two functions in one input tag ?

Comment: You can't wrap javascript functions in html tags.

Comment: I don't want to wrap `javascript function in tag` i just want to mix two `ids` in one `input tag`. JUST ID NOT FULL FUNCTION

Comment: you can't give an element two ids. They are one to one relationships. That's what classes are for.  `class = "class1 class2"`